# Problem in compilation of MINPACK library with CUDA code

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cuda

I need to solve a nonlinear system of equations and I found the MINPACK library to do the job.
But I need the code to work with CUDA and I'm not able to compile the code.

I'm facing this problem:

```
nvcc -arch sm_61 -Iinc -I/usr/local/include obj/main.o -o oi -L/usr/local/lib64 -lcuminpack
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to 'dpmpar' in 'obj/main.o'
make: *** [makefile:55: oi] Erro 255
```

My main file is:

**main.cu**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define __cminpack_double__
#include <cminpack-1/cminpack.h>
#define real __cminpack_real__

typedef struct{
  real fnorm1, fnorm2;
  int info;
  real solution[2];
} ResultType;

__cminpack_attr__ int fcn(void *p, int n, const real *x, real *fvec, int iflag){

    --fvec;
    --x;

    fvec[0] = x[0] + x[0]*x[1] - 4.0;
    fvec[1] = x[0] + x[1] -3.0;

    return 0;
}

__global__ void SolvingSystem(ResultType *pResults){

    int info;

    real fnorm1, fnorm2, tol;

    int n = 2;

    real fvec[2];
    real x[2];

    const int lwa = (n*(3*n + 13))/2;
    real wa[50];

    tol = sqrt(dpmpar(1));

    x[0] = 1.98;
    x[1] = 1.02;

    printf("Initial Guess: %g, %g\n", x[0], x[1]);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    
    cudaSetDevice(0);

    ResultType *reuslt_GPU, *reuslt_CPU;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&reuslt_GPU, sizeof(ResultType));
    cudaMallocHost((void**)&reuslt_CPU, sizeof(ResultType));

    printf("Solving System...\n");

    dim3 grid(1, 1, 1);
    dim3 block(1, 1, 1);

    SolvingSystem<<< grid, block>>>(reuslt_GPU);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("Done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

And my makefile is:

**makefile**

```
# MakeFile

# Program Name
EXE = oi

# Compilers
NVCC := nvcc

ALL_LIBRARIES := cuminpack
LIBDIR :=  /usr/local/lib64

# Directories
SRCDIR := src
OBJDIR := obj
INCDIR := inc /usr/local/include

#Flags
NVCCARCHFLAG := -arch sm_61
NVCCFLAGS    := -std=c++11
LDFLAGS      := $(addprefix -L, $(LIBDIR))

INCLUDES     := $(addprefix -I, $(INCDIR))
LIBRARIES    := $(addprefix -l, $(ALL_LIBRARIES))
LIBRARIES    += 

ALL_CPFLAGS := -MMD
ALL_CPFLAGS += $(NVCCARCHFLAG)
ALL_CPFLAGS += $(NVCCFLAGS)

ALL_LDFLAGS := $(LDFLAGS)


# Files
C_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
CU_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cu)

C_OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(C_FILES))
CU_OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cu, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(CU_FILES))

C_DEP := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(C_FILES))
CU_DEP := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cu, $(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(CU_FILES))

SRC := $(C_FILES) $(CU_FILES)
OBJ := $(C_OBJ) $(CU_OBJ)
DEP := $(C_DEP) $(CU_DEP)

COMPILE.c := $(NVCC) -MMD -g $(INCLUDES) -c
COMPILE.cu := $(NVCC) $(ALL_CPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -dc

.PHONY: all clean

all:$(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCARCHFLAG) $(INCLUDES) $^ -o $@ $(ALL_LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(OBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cu | $(OBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cu) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

# Cleaning up
clean:
    @echo Cleaning up...
    @rm -f -r $(OBJDIR)
    @rm $(EXE)


# Including dependency
-include $(DEP)
```

The main file needs to be finished and that's the reason to some unused variables.

I just can't figure out what is causing this error, I think the problem is in cuminpack library, but I don't now how to fix it.

I'm using cminpack-1.3.8 from this website: http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/cminpack/

I installed the library using `cmake` then `make` and `make install`. Then I went to source folder and did `make cuda`. This last command generated `libcuminpack.a` file in `cuda` directory, then I copied this `.a` file to `/usr/local/lib64` where cmake installed the other libraries files.

If anyone could help me I would be very thankful

**EDIT**

Files from the cminpack library

**cminpack.h**

```
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */
...
#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) || defined(__CUDACC__)
#define __cminpack_attr__ __device__
#ifndef __cminpack_real__
#define __cminpack_float__
#define __cminpack_real__ float
#endif
#define __cminpack_type_fcn_nn__        __cminpack_attr__ int fcn_nn
#define __cminpack_type_fcnder_nn__     __cminpack_attr__ int fcnder_nn
#define __cminpack_type_fcn_mn__        __cminpack_attr__ int fcn_mn
#define __cminpack_type_fcnder_mn__     __cminpack_attr__ int fcnder_mn
#define __cminpack_type_fcnderstr_mn__  __cminpack_attr__ int fcnderstr_mn
#define __cminpack_decl_fcn_nn__
#define __cminpack_decl_fcnder_nn__
#define __cminpack_decl_fcn_mn__
#define __cminpack_decl_fcnder_mn__
#define __cminpack_decl_fcnderstr_mn__
#define __cminpack_param_fcn_nn__
#define __cminpack_param_fcnder_nn__
#define __cminpack_param_fcn_mn__
#define __cminpack_param_fcnder_mn__
#define __cminpack_param_fcnderstr_mn__
...
__cminpack_attr__
__cminpack_real__ CMINPACK_EXPORT __cminpack_func__(dpmpar)( int i );
```

**dpmpar.c**

```
#include "cminpack.h"
#include <float.h>
#include "cminpackP.h"

#define DPMPAR(type,X) _DPMPAR(type,X)
#define _DPMPAR(type,X) type ## _ ## X

__cminpack_attr__
real __cminpack_func__(dpmpar)(int i)
{
/*     ********** */

/*     Function dpmpar */
...
```

Comment: You are calling `dpmpar` in a CUDA kernel. That means that for this to work there *must*  be a dedicated CUDA `__device__` function called  `dpmpar` somewhere which is either defined inline via via the header you import or in the library. If it is in the library then you *must* use CUDA separate compilation and device linking to build the code. If it is not either of those two things, then you are in magical thinking territory and what you are trying to do is use a random host function in a CUDA kernel, and that is never going to work.  I can't tell you which one of these things applies here

Comment: I added parts of the header file and the beginning of `dpmpar.c`  from the cminpack library to the post. If I'm not wrong, the library authors define the `__device__` function through `__cminpack_attr__`. So, this means I need to use CUDA separte compilation and device linking, right? But this is not done with the `-dc` flag?

Comment: Having just looked at the library I see this "cuda needs \_\_device\_\_ source code compiled inline with kernel".  So your entire build process won't work with this library as supplied. You might be able to make your own device library from the code, but you would need to make a new Makefile for the library yourself as far as I can tell

Comment: I thought about what you said and I solved the problem!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @MatheusIurk is MINPACK a parallel algorithm? I'll be glad to be wrong because I thought it was serial.

Comment: @Olumide I think you're right. But in my code I needed each thread solving the nonlinear system of equations. So thinking now I'm using the library in a serial way but inside a CUDA parallel algorithm. I hope you understood what I needed!! Have a nice year!!

Comment: @MatheusIurk I understand what you mean and it is unusual -- unless you are developing some sort of genetic algorithm. I haven't taken a close look at MINPACK but you need to be careful that the algorithm does not do any branching and all loops have a fixed number of iterations. If not you are likely to get terrible performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [talonmies's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) comment I was able to compile the code defining the `__device__` function `dpmpar` in `main.cu` file.

Then I found this post https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/external-calls-to-device-functions/17737 where the guy answered that CUDA doesn't have a linker on the device side, so it's not possible to call a `__device__` function from a different `.cu` file.

With this in mind, I copied only the files that I needed from the library and made some modifications, like changing `__cminpack_attr__` to `__device__` and I rewrote the header file too. So basically I made my own device library (thank's again to [talonmies's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies)).

The last thing I did was move all this new files to the same folder where my `main.cu` and my `makefile` lives and I rewrote the `makefile`.

Now the code compile fine!!